# How to use reset_login endpoint with Plaid?

Tags: node.js, plaid

I don't understand how the reset_login endpoint works. In the sandbox mode, do I need to enter the usual credentials user_good, pass_good and then on the onSuccess callback make the request to the reset_login point? or what is the right flow?

I don't understand because if I try to just make the request to the reset endpoint with the onsuccess callback then I don't have the access_token that I need as a parameter for that function, but if I do make it after, how is it going to trigger the ITEM_LOGIN_REQURIED error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call the reset_login endpoint from your backend after an item has already been created and you have the access token. Here's what the call looks like in Ruby:

```
client.sandbox.sandbox_item.reset_login("access-token-goes-here")
```

...where `client` is a Plaid client object.